# Phonegap - Force Screen Pop up Alert

Tags: cordova

I'm new to Phonegap and I'm currently building a simple alarm application. Everything is working, except that I don't know how to turn on the screen and show the application when it's time to play the alarm (e.g. like how normal phone scheduled alarm works).

I'm using jQuerymobile.

Answer (score 0):

check out the localnotifications plugin... https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/LocalNotifications

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply. Actually I've been looking into that plugin(the android version by the way) but I haven't been able to fix the java files correctly as per instructions like:

Fix the import in AlarmReceiver.java around line 67 where R.drawable.ic_launcher is referenced so it matches an icon in your project.

LocalNotification.java file got some issues or syntax errors as well..

Comment: There should be a file in your res/drawables* folders called ic_launcher.jpg/png. This is the icon that will be shown in the status bar when the notification occurs. Just copy any old jpg/png of that name into the res/drawable folders to get things going.